No ringtone when i do a call forwarding with Twilio
I have an issue on my in-app call feature that uses Twilio to implement a call forwarding
This is the workflow of my call is :

user calls the twilio number
twilio call a route from my backend
backend return a TwiMl :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<Response>
<Dial callerId="number" answerOnBridge="true" ringTone="fr">
        <Number statusCallbackEvent="completed" statusCallback="callback" statusCallbackMethod="POST">number</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>


Twilio Forward the call

My problem is, there is no ringtone during the call until the callee answer the call.
The answer I saw on docs and here is to add answerOnBridge="true", but this doesn't work in my case. Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem ?
